Alembic - Inverted workflow upgrade/downgrade
I have this issue with Alembic + FastAPI + PostgreSQL
SQL Alchemy Alembic generates migrations in reverse, downgrade creates the table and upgrade drops it, while the database is empty.
For example:
alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Testing 2"
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected removed index 'ix_Site_keyword' on 'Site'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected removed table 'Site'
  Generating /app/migrations/versions/1e3a0f40182c_testing_2.py ...  done

I've checked the file and I got this one:
"""Testing 2

Revision ID: 1e3a0f40182c
Revises: 928ab2a61fa7
Create Date: 2024-04-04 08:32:29.784316

"""
from typing import Sequence, Union

from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision: str = '1e3a0f40182c'
down_revision: Union[str, None] = '928ab2a61fa7'
branch_labels: Union[str, Sequence[str], None] = None
depends_on: Union[str, Sequence[str], None] = None


def upgrade() -> None:
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.drop_index('ix_Site_keyword', table_name='Site')
    op.drop_table('Site')
    # ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade() -> None:
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('Site',
    sa.Column('id', sa.UUID(), autoincrement=False, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('title', sa.VARCHAR(), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.Column('keyword', sa.VARCHAR(), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.Column('description', sa.TEXT(), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.Column('is_active', sa.BOOLEAN(), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.Column('created_at', postgresql.TIMESTAMP(), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.Column('updated_at', postgresql.TIMESTAMP(), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.Column('deleted_at', postgresql.TIMESTAMP(), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id', name='Site_pkey')
    )
    op.create_index('ix_Site_keyword', 'Site', ['keyword'], unique=False)
    # ### end Alembic commands ###

Why do this one? If I switch the blocks (put upgrade block to downgrade block and vice-versa) If I run the next automigration, I got the all delete syntax in upgrade function... so, always I have to rewrite the code.
What's going on here?
UPDATE: This is my env.py file.
from logging.config import fileConfig

from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool
from database.orm import Base
from alembic import context


config = context.config

if config.config_file_name is not None:
    fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

target_metadata = Base.metadata



def run_migrations_offline() -> None:
    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    context.configure(
        url=url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
        dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"},
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online() -> None:
    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section, {}),
        prefix="sqlalchemy.",
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()


It means alembic can't find your Site table. You are probably creating Site somewhere not in database.orm. Python doesn't run that part of code, so there is no table at metadata for alembic, but it's found in current database introspection, so alembic deletes it. You should import your models near from database.orm import Base of env.py. But imo it's better to create database.__init__.py and import Base and other models (e.g from .site import *) right there, so whenever you are addressing Base, your models are already imported

I made with another way:
I imported from the env.py file the database models like this:
from database.orm import Base from models import site that's all.

Finally:
env.py
from database.orm import Base
from models import site

models.site.py
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, String, DateTime, Text

from database.orm import Base
import uuid
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID
from sqlalchemy import func


def generate_uuid():
    return str(uuid.uuid4())

class Site(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Site"

    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, unique=True, default=generate_uuid)
    title = Column(String)
    keyword = Column(String, index=True)
    description = Column(Text)
    is_active = Column(Boolean, default=True)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, default=func.now)
    updated_at = Column(DateTime, default=func.now)
    deleted_at = Column(DateTime, default=func.now)

databases.orm.py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://postgres:example@database/db_new"

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL
)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()

def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

Run:
alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Tes4"
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'Site'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added index ''ix_Site_keyword'' on '('keyword',)'
  Generating /app/migrations/versions/f3d6623e75ec_tes4.py ...  done

migrations.versions.f3d6623e75ec_tes4.py
"""Tes4

Revision ID: f3d6623e75ec
Revises: 
Create Date: 2024-04-04 15:19:09.018548

"""
from typing import Sequence, Union

from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa


# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision: str = 'f3d6623e75ec'
down_revision: Union[str, None] = None
branch_labels: Union[str, Sequence[str], None] = None
depends_on: Union[str, Sequence[str], None] = None


def upgrade() -> None:
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('Site',
    sa.Column('id', sa.UUID(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('title', sa.String(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('keyword', sa.String(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('description', sa.Text(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('is_active', sa.Boolean(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('created_at', sa.DateTime(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('updated_at', sa.DateTime(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('deleted_at', sa.DateTime(), nullable=True),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id'),
    sa.UniqueConstraint('id')
    )
    op.create_index(op.f('ix_Site_keyword'), 'Site', ['keyword'], unique=False)
    # ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade() -> None:
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.drop_index(op.f('ix_Site_keyword'), table_name='Site')
    op.drop_table('Site')
    # ### end Alembic commands ###

